# If the iteration $x^{k+1}=x^k-t_kH_k^{-1}\nabla f(x^k)$ converges superlinearly to a stationary point $x^*\ne x^k$, then $t_k\to 1$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

Let

- $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
- $(H_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}\subseteq\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$
- $x^0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $$x^{k+1}:=x^k+t_k d^k\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb{N}_0\tag{1}$$ with $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}\subseteq (0,\infty)$ and $$H_kd^k+\nabla f(x^k)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb{N}_0\tag{2}$$
- $x^\ast\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\left\{x^k:k\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$ with $x_k\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}x^*$ and $\nabla^2f(x^*)\in\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Suppose $x_k\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}x^*$ superlinearly, i.e. $$\frac{\left\|x^{k+1}-x^*\right\|}{\left\|x^k-x^*\right\|}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}0\tag{3}$$ and $x^*$ is stationary, i.e. $$\nabla f(x^*)=0\tag{4}$$

**How can we conclude, that we must have $t_k\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}1$?**

---

Clearly, by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we've got $$-t_kH_k^{-1}\nabla f(x^k)=x^{k+1}-x^k\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}0\tag{5}\;,$$ but is that the right track? Unfortunately, I'm unable to proceed.

---

**EDIT:** If someone can prove the statement under further restrictions, e.g. $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$-boundedness of all $H_k^{-1}$, I would be happy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just incomplete. I will illustrate the argument using the Newton method, and sketch it for the usual quasi Newton framework.

**For Newton method:**

Assume $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is non-singular and $x^0$ is sufficiently near $x^*$ such that $H_k = \nabla^2 f(x^k)$ is non-singular for every $k\ge 0$ (the usual assumptions for local convergence analysis of the Newton method).
Then, we have
$$ x^{k+1} - x^* = (x^k + d^k - x^*) - (1-t_k)d^k.$$

The left hand side is $\mathcal o(\|x^k - x^*\|)$ by assumption.
On the right hand side, the first term 
\begin{align} 
x^k + d^k - x^*
&= x^k - x^* - H_k^{-1}\nabla f(x^k) \\
&= x^k - x^* - H_k^{-1}\int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x^* + t(x^k - x^*))(x^k - x^*) \;\mathrm dt \\
&= H_k^{-1} \underbrace{\left(\int_0^1 H_k - \nabla^2 f(x^* + t(x^k - x^*)) \;\mathrm dt  \right)}_{=\mathcal o(1)} (x^k - x^*)\\
\end{align} 
is $\mathcal o(\|x^k - x^*\|)$ by continuity of $\nabla^2 f$ at $x^*$.
Therefore the second term $(1-t_k)d^k$ must be $\mathcal o(\|x^k - x^*\|)$. 
On other hand, we have
$$ \frac{\| x^k - x^* + d^k \|}{\|x^k - x^*\|} \ge 1 - \frac{\|d^k\|}{\|x^k -x^* \|}. $$
Thus, $\liminf_{k\to\infty} \|d^k\| / \|x^k -x^* \| \ge 1$ and
$1-t_k$ tends to 0. That is, $t_k\to 1$.

**For Quasi Newton method:**

In that case, we need the additional assumption that $\limsup_{k\to\infty} \| H_k^{-1} \| < \infty$.
The essential part in proof for the Newton method was, that the Newton method converges superlinearly even without the step size $t_k$. 
A sufficient condition for the property at quasi Newton framework is for example
$$  \tag{*} (H_k - \nabla^2 f(x^*))d^k = \mathcal o(\| d^k \|).$$

Since $H_k^{-1}$ is bounded and $x^k\to x^*$ 
we have $d^k = -H_k \nabla f(x^*)\to 0$ and obtain
$$ \nabla f(x^{k}+d^k) = \underbrace{\left(\int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x^* + t(x^{k} + d^k - x^*)) \;\mathrm d t\right)}_{=: G_k}(x^{k} + d^k - x^*). $$
For $k$ sufficiently large, $G_k$ is non-singular and we have $G_k^{-1}\to \left(\nabla^2 f(x^*)\right)^{-1}$.
Thus, without loss of generality assume $\|G_k^{-1}\| \le \gamma$ for all $k$.
On other hand, notice that
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x^{k} + d^k) 
&= (\nabla f(x^k + d^k) - \nabla f(x^{k})) - H_k d^k \\
&= \underbrace{(\nabla^2 f(x^*) - H_k)d^k}_{=\mathcal o(\|d^k\|)}
+ \underbrace{\nabla f(x^{k}+d^k) - (\nabla f(x^k) + \nabla^2 f(x^*) d^k)}_{=\mathcal o(\|d^k\|)}.
\end{align}
Now, for $\gamma_k = \|\nabla f(x^{k} + d^k)\| / \|d^k\|$ we have
\begin{align} 
\|x^{k} + d^k - x^* \|
&\le \gamma \|\nabla f(x^{k} + d^k)\| \\
&= \gamma \gamma_k \|d^k\| \\
&\le \gamma \gamma_k (\|x^k + d^k - x^* \| + \| x^k - x^* \|) 
\end{align}
and
$$ \frac{\| x^k + d^k - x^* \|}{\| x^k - x^* \|} \le \frac{\gamma\gamma_k}{1-\gamma\gamma_k} \to 0. $$

**Note:** The condition (*) implies also that $x^k\to x^*$ super linearly.

Comment: @HansEngler has already provided a counter example for the general case and you've proved the statement only for the special case $H_k=\nabla^2f(x^k)$. So, you haven't stated it explicitly, but you agree, that we cannot prove the statement for arbitrary $H_k\in\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: not for arbitrary $H_k$. $H_k$ needs to approximate $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ in the direction $x^{k+1}-x^k$.

Comment: However, your solution for $H_k=\nabla^2f(x^k)$ has the problem, that we only know that $\nabla^2f(x^*)$ is regular. So, we need to assume that $x^0$ is chosen from a sufficient small environment of $x^*$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d yes, as I wrote it for the Newton method. It works the same for bfgs method. In fact, any locally super linear convergent quasi Newton method has that property.

Comment: What's the definition of "approximate $\nabla^2f(x^*)$ in the direction $x^{k+1}-x^k$"? Can provide an answer for such $H_k$?

Comment: So, one of the "usual assumption for the Newton method" is, that there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that the statement is true for any $x^0\in B_\varepsilon(x^*)$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Oh I see the confusion. I had typo in the last formula and forgot ${}^2$ at $\nabla^2$. "$H_k$ approximates $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ in direction $x^{k+1} - x^k$" means $$ (H_k - \nabla^2 f(x^*))(x^{k+1} - x^k) = \mathcal o(\| x^{k+1} - x^k \|).$$
That condition is equivalent to $x^k\to x^*$ locally super linear. That is true for example for the BFGS and DFP formula for Quasi Newton Method.

Comment: @0xbadf00d you also need that $H_k^{-1}$ is bounded.

Comment: So, even when the $B_k=\nabla^2f(x^k)$ are regular, we cannot assume, that the $A_k$, consistently approximating $\left\{B_k\right\}$, are regular, too? What's the way out of this dilemma? If we assume, that the $H_k$ satisfy $$(H_k - \nabla^2 f(x^*))(x^{k+1} - x^k) = \mathcal o(\| x^{k+1} - x^k \|)\;,$$ can we show that the $H_k$ need to be regular?

Comment: You need to assume that $H_k$ is non-singular. But that is rather natural assumption in that context. For example the BFGS and DFP formula guarantee that $H_k$ is non-singular, in fact positive definite.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: So, I fixed the argument for Newton. Without Lipschitz continuous Hessian, the convergence is only super linear. My bad. I also add the argument for the quasi newton methods. I am still trying to show that super linear convergence implies the condition (*) I assumed. But, probably (*) is stronger than super linear convergence, as (*) implies the super linear convergence without step size $=1$.

Comment: As I've written in the other question: For arbitrary $\left\{x^k\right\}$ converging to $x^*$ with $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ regular and $x^k\ne x^*$ the statements "$x^k\to x^*$ superlinearly and $\nabla f(x^*)=0$", "$\left\{\delta^k:=x^{k+1}-x^k\right\}$ is Newton-like" and "$\left\|\nabla f(x^k)+\nabla^2f(x^*)\delta^k\right\|=o\left(\left\|\delta^k\right\|\right)$" are equivalent. So, if we use an explicit sequence $$x^{k+1}:=x^k+t_kd^k\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ with

Comment: a given $x^0\in\mathbb R^n$, $\left\{t_k\right\}\subset(0,\infty)$ and $$d^k:=-H_k^{-1}\nabla f(x^k)$$ for a given sequence $\left\{H_k\right\}\subseteq\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, it is no surprise that (as long as we've stil got $x^k\ne x^*$, $x^k\to x^*$ and $\nabla^2f(x^*)\in\text{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$) the statement is still true. Moreover, the second statement is equivalent to "$\left\{d^k\right\}$ is Newton-like" and the third statement is equivalent to "$\left\|\left(\nabla^2f(x^*)-H_k\right)d^k\right\|=o \left( \left\| d^k \right\| \right)$" (both can be easily shown).

Comment: So, it would be of no worth to consider this explicit sequence, if we were not able to show, that the first statement also implies that $t_k\to 1$. So, this is the only thing we need to show. Do you agree up to this point? $$-$$ Can you explain, why the implication "first statement $\Rightarrow$ $t_k\to 1$" is important enough, that we consider this special sequence at all? Maybe the message is "if you're only interested in superlinear convergence, you don't need to worry about any step size strategy other than $t_k\equiv 1$". Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Basically yes. Usually you search the step size $t_k$ in some predefined interval. In (quasi) Newton method you know is something like $[1/2, 2]$. For example for gradient methods there is no such kind of heuristic (at least not that I am aware of).

Comment: @0xbadf00d it is the same

Comment: Last question: You've written something like $(\nabla^2 f(x^*)-H_k)d^k=\mathcal o(\|d^k\|)$. Is this a shorthand for $\left\|(\nabla^2 f(x^*)-H_k)d^k\right\|=\mathcal o(\|d^k\|)$?

Comment: So, it's common practice to write (possibly at the end of a long equation where you don't want to write down the norm each time) $f(x)=o(\left\|g(x)\right\|)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d for multi variate $f$, $f(x) = o(\|g(x)\|)$ is defined as $\|f(x)\| = o(\|g(x)\|)$. It is just notation.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. You can always replace $t_k$ with $\tilde t_k = \lambda_kt_k$ and $H_k$ with $\tilde H_k = \lambda_kH_k$ and get the exact same sequence $x_k$. But now $\tilde t_k$ can have any behavior you want, the sequence can even diverge. And you can certainly arrange for $\lim_{k \to \infty} t_k = c$ for any $c \ne 0$, just by changing $H_k$ to $c t_k^{-1}H_k$ and replacing all $t_k$ with the constant $c$.

A statement like this cannot be proved. You cannot infer convergence properties of a factor in a product from assumptions about the convergence of the product.

Comment: Please explain which additional assumptions you would like to add. Do you mean that each $H_k^{-1}$ should be $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$-bounded?

Comment: See my edited response.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\tilde{t}_k=c$?